# passing a Datetime from SQL to an asp textbox but getting different result

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, datetime

I am passing a DateTime value from SQL Table to a Textbox in ASP.Net using

> <asp:TextBox ID="dateTxt" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("date").ToString()%>' class="form-control"></asp:TextBox>

The Value in SQL is 2023-02-08 16:01:49.153

But shows in the textbox as 2/8/2023 09:07:13 PM

I want it to show as the exact SQL value.

This is how I get the value from the Database

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT *   FROM   ThisTable where stage = 'pending'", con)
                    {
                        CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    };
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    da.Fill(dt);
                        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                        GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add

```
Text='<%# Eval("date", "{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}") %>'
```

and that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have used this it works for me

```
Text='<%# Eval("date").ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Eval("date").ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
```

Comment: I tried that but I needed the milliseconds and when I added the fff for milliseconds it would just put "000". If figured out how to do it though. Thank you for trying. I posted the answer.